# Limit a parameter of ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
item = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos@u, Sin@u, u/10}, {u, 0, 40}];

 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos@u, Sin@u, u/10}, {u, 0, 40}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0.5, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 4}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

- (* I want to get a graph of the curve that is cut by the plane. 
  How could I get the image of item when limit the Sin[u]==0.5 ？*)

*

*thanks for help , i have known how to get what i want   *

```
 gra = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20},
 PlotPoints ->100, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, y-0.5],
Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], BoundaryStyle -> None,
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]

pp = Cases[Normal@gra, Point[___], Infinity]
ListPlot[Cases[pp, {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, c}, Infinity], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], AxesLabel -> {"x", "z"}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}]]
```

[image: when y==0.5]

[image: those points]

Comment: Look up `RegionFunction`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: sorry ,my english is not well . thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) or you could put a condition on the function being plotted,

```
{ParametricPlot3D[{Cos@u, Sin@u, u/10}, {u, 0, 40}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Sin[u] <= 0.5]], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  If[Sin[u] <= 0.5, {Cos@u, Sin@u, u/10}, Indeterminate], {u, 0, 40}]}
```

[image]

Comment: For the second possibility, one could also use `ConditionalExpression[]`: `ParametricPlot3D[ConditionalExpression[{Cos[u], Sin[u], u/10}, Sin[u] <= 0.5], {u, 0, 40}]`

Comment: But then I wouldn't get to use the very first programming function I ever learned, from back in third grade.  Okay, I may have used `GOTO` first...

Comment: I'll only give you a pass on that one if you eventually come up with an answer that uses `Goto[]`. >:)

Comment: More seriously, is `ConditionalExpression` more efficient?  It's 4 characters longer than the `If` statement, but this isn't codegolf so that doesn't really matter

Comment: Haven't really seen a difference in practice, so it's really the user's call.